# I can't get changes from develop

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I did merge my development into my branch. After I revert the merge commit. Later on, I did two commits pushed and I merge develop into my branch but there aren't any changes but there are changes. How can I fix it? My git experience is so bad :/

Comment: "there aren't any changes but there are changes" <-- I don't understand this

Answer (score 0):

I think with "I revert the merge commit" you mean you did a `git revert`. This adds an additional commit that reverts the changes done in the merge commit. So in your history you have still the merge commit and this is the problem.

Since you have already merged, with the next merge from develop you will get only the changes in develop after the merge commit.

You should have done a `git reset` to the commit before the merge. You can still do this and then `cherry-pick` your two newer commits. When you want to bring the changed branch to the remote repository, you will have to do a `git push --force`.